# Conditional regex match based on two non-capturing groups

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I've been looking for what seems like hours, and I just cannot find a solution for this. My regex skills are terrible but I'm sure for someone with the knowledge this will be easy.

```
/^(?:[1-9]{1,3}GB)|(?:[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}TB)$/i
```

As you can see it's pretty simple. I just need to match one or the other but I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Examples:

```
<?= $validate->data('100GB'); ?>
```

This should match since it's 3 digits followed by "GB."

```
<?= $validate->data('2.65TB'); ?>
```

This should also match since it's 1 digit followed by period, followed by two more digits, followed by "TB."

EDIT: I needed to modify the numeric count but still doesn't perform as expected.

For anyone interested, here is the final regex.

```
/^(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:GB|TB))|(?:[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}(?:GB|TB))$/i
```

Comment: an example or two would be helpful. Along with expected results

Comment: Why are you not allowing [0] with GB? If it's a regex for say Hard drives then it's rather common they are 500, or 700 GB.

Comment: I have added some examples. @Andreas - There will always be some amount of data, will never be 0.

Comment: But your example above is 100GB. That is two zeros. do you see them?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/6undez/2 See here. You need to include zeros in your regex.

Comment: @Andreas - You are correct, oversight on my part. Trying to do too much at once. Please add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not including zeros in your regex, that is why the pattern fails.

`[1-9]{3}` will only match three digits 1-9. So 111 is a match. 234 is also a match.
But 500 is not.

With this regex: `([0-9]{3}GB)|([0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}TB)` you will be able to catch the zeros and it will not limit you to two digit TB disks.

https://regex101.com/r/6undez/3

EDIT: In case you want to match `100 GB` note the space. You can use this regex:
https://regex101.com/r/6undez/4
`([0-9]{3}\s?GB)|([0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}\s?TB)`

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. I updated with space in the pattern if that is something you need.

Answer (score 0):

For increased efficiency and brevity (compared to the final pattern in the question), use this pattern:

```
/^(?:\d{1,3}|\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2})[GT]B$/i
```

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5PEtDn/1)

Improvements:

- consolidated branches
- used `\d` instead of `[0-9]` for brevity
- used character class `[GT]` for brevity/efficiency

---

If you are going with Andreas' pattern, I'd recommend this:

```
/^(?:\d{1,3} ?GB)|(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})? ?TB)$/i
```

Improvements:

- added anchors
- used non-capturing groups
- used `\d` instead of `[0-9]` for brevity
- used  instead of `\s` for efficiency
- escaped the `.` for accuracy/efficiency
- made decimals optional for TB branch